Export to xlsx in VSCode SQL Developer Extension
This is yet another "Oracle SQL Developer has this feature but I can't find it in the VSCode extension" question.
In SQL Developer I can select 'excel 2003+ (xlsx)' to export to xlsx.

This option is not (yet?) present in the equivalent export dropdown in the VSCode extension.

The obvious workaround is to export as csv, open in any program that can save xlsx files (such as MS Excel) and then save as an xlsx. I don't want to have to do this, and would rather have xlsx selected as my default export format.
